# How do i get 10 random values in python?

Tags: python

I am new to programming and I got stuck with random number generation. I can simply generate random numbers using random function "randint" but could not generate set of random numbers. For instance i want to get 10 random numbers.

```
from random import randint
x = randint(1, 100)
y = randint(1, 100)
isFailedTest = (5<=x<=15) and (10<=y<=11)
selected_test = [x,y]
while (isFailedTest == False):
```

I can generate 1 random number at one time but not 10 at one time. Here 1 number mean 2 dimensional number example (x,y) = (10,20)  I want to get 10 random numbers (x,y) after my while condition. How do I achieve that? I am very new to programming so could not figure out what could be done. All help/ suggestion/ recommendation is highly appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: As a Java programmer, I would simply write a for loop. There might be a more "pythonic" way to do this however.

Comment: Use randint function 10 times to get 10 random numbers. In your code, you had used randint two times to get two random numbers for x and y. Yes, you can use randint as many time as you like. If you want to make array of random number, set random number into array one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requirement - "Here 1 number mean 2 dimensional number example (x,y) = (10,20) I want to get 10 random numbers (x,y)"

```
>>> from random import randint as r
>>> array = [ (r(1,100), r(1,100)) for i in xrange(10)]
```

Answer (score 6):

**Simple solution**

```
array = [(randint(1, 100), randint(1, 100)) for i in range(10)]
```

**Better solution**

The following solution is more flexible and reusable.

```
from functools import partial
from random import randint


def randints(count, *randint_args):
    ri = partial(randint, *randint_args)
    return [(ri(), ri()) for _ in range(count)]


print(randints(10, 1, 100))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do:

```
from random import randint
randoms = []
for i in range(10):
    randoms.append((randint(1,100),randint(1,100)))
```

Then `randoms` will be an array of 10 integers, randomly generated between 1 and 100 (inclusive).

To be quite clear: what is going on here is that you make an empty list called `randoms`. Then  the `for loop` executes ten times, each time appending a new tuple of two random integers to the list `randoms`.

Comment: Use list comprehensions instead of a loop.

Comment: @Tichodroma 1. Do you really think list comprehensions are appropriate in an answer for a total beginner? 2. I don't think there is a strong case for a list comprehension over a loop here. At a bytecode level, the two are nearly equivalent. A list comprehension is a *tiny* bit faster, and no more. See here for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108488/are-list-comprehensions-and-functional-functions-faster-than-for-loops

Comment: 1. Yes. Teach pythonic Python. 2. We don't talk about bytecode but about pythonic code.

Comment: @Tichodroma 1. What's the point in "teaching" pythonic Python if the asker doesn't even know how to populate a list? Just look at the OP's source code, and you know that a list comprehension will be utterly incomprehensible to them. (No offense to the OP intended.) 2. How can you dismiss the topic of bytecode-level efficiency?

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import randint
r = []
N = 10
for x in range(N):
    a = randint(5,15)   # rand number between 5 and 15
    b = randint(10,11)  # rand number between 10 and 11
    r.append((a,b))

# r <-- contains N tuples with random numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

NumPy should do the job

```
np.random.randint(low=1, high=100, size=10)
```