# scipy.quad trouble for decreasing functions over large ranges

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, exponential, quad

I have a problem with `scipy.integrate.quad`. In short, I have a really long and complicated set of nested functions and integrals which include an integral of a decreasing function which **must** be integrated over the specific range 10^2 < x < 10^20.

To demonstrate this problem simply, consider the integral of y=x^(-2) between these values using `scipy.integrate.quad`:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

def func(x,z):
    "decreasing function to test"
    # print x, x**-2.
    return x**(-2.)

# Test quad:
print('Quad', quad(lambda x: func(x, 0.), 1e2, 1e20)[0])
```

The true answer to this integral is 0.01, however `quad` returns a very small value, and by uncommenting the print line in the function you can see that it only integrates over the largest x values (or is biased that way due to the log scale of the x-axis). I need to find some way of fixing this problem.

I know that you can get the correct answer by using other methods such as the Simpsons or trapezoidal rules:

```
from scipy.integrate import simpson, trapezoid

xarray=np.logspace(2, 20, 1000)

print('Simpson logspace x', simpson(func(xarray, 0.), xarray))
print('Trapezoid logspace x', trapezoid(func(xarray, 0.), xarray))
```

However, these include passing an array into the function, which is not possible with my actual code. Thus I'd have to include a `for` loop to generate a y array to integrate with, which slows the whole program down unacceptably.

Is there any trick to making `quad` work for this sort of x range, or anything which works like `quad` which I can use instead?

Comment: `quad(lambda x: func(x,0.),1e2,np.inf)` will work.

Comment: And do you really need a `for` loop to generate `y` for your `x`? Why don't your functions support element-wise array operations? (Anyway the `quad` approach should be more accurate if you get it to work properly)

Comment: Thanks guys for replying. Unfortunately cel, for my function

        quad(lambda x: func(x,0.),1e2,np.inf)

doesn't help. It returns a negative (wrong!) number which doesn't match the simpson or trapezium rules between 10^2 and 10^20.

Andras, the reason my function doesn't support element-wise operation at the moment is because it loads in arrays at the base level and I haven't programmed it to handle taking arrays at the top. I may have to rewrite it if needs be, but it'll take ages, and I hoped there was a simpler fix to quad.

Comment: Does that negative return value refer to the `1/x^2` example? If the negative is for your actual problem: are you sure it's wrong? And have you tried, just for proof-of-concept, using [a list comprehension instead of a for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22108640/5067311) to generate your data for `trapz` (to see whether that's marginally faster)? And next time you might want to ping cel by adding @cel to your comment, otherwise they won't get a notification (I just left this question open just for such an occasion).

Comment: There's also the `points` argument that you can use if you have some feeling about how the function behaves.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [variable substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution) `x = exp(t)`.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad

# original
def f(x):
    return x**-2.

a, b = 10**2., 10**20.
quad(f, a, b)
# (2.754484024437256e-17, 5.2212478622117524e-17)

# with substitution
def g(t):
    expt = np.exp(t)
    return f(expt) * expt

quad(g, np.log(a), np.log(b))
# (0.00999999999999998, 3.0000387625246216e-09)
```