# strange syntax error for Python tuple operation

Tags: python

Here is the code and error message in PyCharm. If anyone have any insights what is wrong with the syntax, it will be great. :)

`candidates` is an array of non-negative integers, and `target` is a positive integer. For example, `candidates` are `[10,1,2,7,6,1,5]` and `target` is `10`.

I am using Python 2.6 on OSX.

```
def combinationSum2(self, candidates, target):
    candidates.sort()
    table = [None] + [set() for i in range(target)]
    for i in candidates:
        if i > target:
            break
        for j in range(target - i, 0, -1):
            table[i + j] |= {elt + (i,) for elt in table[j]}
        table[i].add((i,))
    return map(list, table[target])
```

[image]

Comment: Entered into my interpreters (2 and 3), no syntax error.

Comment: Could be a problem with tab or spaces?

Comment: Set comprehensions only exist in Python 2.7 and later.

Comment: @BrenBarn, thanks a lot, want to confirm my understanding of set comprehension is correct, set comprehension means construct a set without using set(), but using {}? Here is more details for what I studied. http://love-python.blogspot.com/2012/12/set-comprehensions-in-python.html

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, if you could advise whether my above understanding of set comprehension is correct, it will be great.

Comment: @toti08, if you could advise whether my above understanding of set comprehension is correct, it will be great.

Comment: Set comprehension is like list comprehension: a literal expression for the object you want to create, without needing to start with an empty iterable and then add to it in an explicit traditional loop (e.g. `myset = set(); for i in range(5): myset.add(i)`).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, great answer. So for list comprehension, I should use `{}`?

Comment: No. List comprehensions use `[]`, set comprehensions use `{}`. [This page of the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) describes list, set, and dictionary comprehensions.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, what is the benefit of set comprehension, comparing to not using it?

Comment: See [my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34061397/strange-syntax-error-for-python-tuple-operation?noredirect=1#comment55919686_34061397) regarding concision.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, want to confirm we are on the same page, the only benefit is "without needing to start with an empty iterable"? Thanks. :)

Comment: Pretty much. Also see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for more.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, read the document, but does not feel too much benefit other than shorter line of code? I could be wrong, appreciate if you could highlight 1 or 2 points which you think set or list comprehension is more benefit than not using it? Thanks and have a good weekend.

Comment: "Shorter and clearer" is a real benefit. Readability counts. There may sometimes be slight performance benefits in a comprehension, but that's not the important part.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, thanks but why performance could be even better? I thought underlying they should generate the same C/Java code?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108488/are-list-comprehensions-and-functional-functions-faster-than-for-loops) for some more information.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, thanks a lot! Could you add a reply to my question? I will mark it as answered so that it benefit other people as well. :)

Comment: @LinMa - Nope; the question is closed, so no answers can be added. Don't worry about it.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, thanks. My initial ask is just credit more for your help. Have a good day. :)