# Find letters in string without using for loop

Tags: python

I was trying to figure out how to list just the letters in a string and ignore the numbers or any other characters. I figured out how to do it using the for loop, but I couldn't find out how to do it without using the for loop. 
This is how I used the for loop:

```
>>> a = "Today is April 1, 2016"
    for i in a:
         if i.isalpha():
              list(i)
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: So your title should be `without using..`?

Comment: `re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]","",a)` ?

Comment: What is `list(i)` supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#filter) for this:

```
>>> ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, a))
'TodayisApril'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list(set([x for x in a if x.isalpha()]))
```

this should do it :)

Comment: From the question: `I figured out how to do it using the for loop, but I couldn't find out how to do it without using the for loop.` and this answer uses `for` loop.

Comment: It's a list comprehension actually ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108488/are-list-comprehensions-and-functional-functions-faster-than-for-loops

Comment: Thank you for all of the answers! I ended up finding filter for this.