# How to read two repeated subsequent values from a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have a list `L = [1,2,3,4,5,6]` and I need to retrieve pairs as follows:

```
[1,2] , [2,3], [3,4], [4,5], [5,6]
```

My current solution is create two utility lists:

```
U1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
U2 = [2,3,4,5,6]
```

And use `zip` built in function to get the desired result.

Is there any better way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's like your solution with the utility lists but a bit shorter:

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

for i in zip(L, L[1:]):
    print(list(i))
# [1, 2]
# [2, 3]
# [3, 4]
# [4, 5]
# [5, 6]
```

This works as expected because [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip) stops as soon as one iterable is exhausted.

You could additionally use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) to convert the items immediatly:

```
for i in map(list, zip(L, L[1:])):
    print(i)
```

or if you want the whole thing converted to a list of lists:

```
list(map(list, zip(L, L[1:])))
# [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6]]
```

---

If your lists are really long creating a new list (because I sliced it with `[1:]`) might be expensive, then you could avoid this by using [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
for i in zip(L, islice(L, 1, None)):
    print(list(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[[L[i], L[i+1]] for i in range(len(L)-1)]
```

Usually, a list comprehension will be much faster than a for loop in python

Comment: List comprehensions are **usually** only faster in constructing lists in iteration, however are not faster in the case of iteration for other purposes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108488/are-list-comprehensions-and-functional-functions-faster-than-for-loops