# How to catch all the iteration of a "for" loop in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the result of every iterations of a for loop into a list, but when I run my code, I only get the last iteration's result in my list.

```
import ipaddress

user_input = input("")

network = ipaddress.IPv4Network(user_input)

for i in network.hosts():
    ipaddresses = i
print(ipaddresses)
```

The result is -

```
10.192.32.0/24
10.192.32.254
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the results of every iterations of a for loop into a list, you need a [list](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html) to store the values at each iteration.

```
import ipaddress
user_input = input("")
network = ipaddress.IPv4Network(user_input)

ipaddresses = [] #initiate an empty list

for i in network.hosts():
    ipaddresses.append(i)
print(ipaddresses)
```

Answer (score 0):

You always set  ipadresses to the current value of i and therefor ipadress is always a string of the last i it was set equal to. A faster way to achieve your goal is to do a list comprehension:

```
    import ipaddress

    user_input = input("")
    network = ipaddress.IPv4Network(user_input)

    ipaddresses = [i for i in network.hosts()]

    print(ipaddresses)
```

Comment: A faster way to achieve your goal is to do a list comprehension? it is pythonic but not faster.

Comment: List comprehensions are faster than doing the same in a for loop  if I'm not completely mistaken

Comment: You are completely mistaken.

Comment: I'm sorry but they are, even for a simple sum of 100 elements, a list comprehension is more than twice as fast loop over the elements. Just try it out.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108488/are-list-comprehensions-and-functional-functions-faster-than-for-loops

Comment: Yes and if i may cite it  **A list comprehension is usually a tiny bit faster than the precisely equivalent for loop (that actually builds a list)**. So first i didn't claim that it is way faster for every use and  i also tried it before with the timeit method for my claim. So you are wrong here, not me.

Comment: Read all answers. It is sometimes slower.

Comment: Anyway, the point of a list comprehension is not speed, but readability and writing comfort. It reduces the boilerplate of building simple lists, but trying hard to build a complex list through a comprehension might lead to awful things with multiple `for`s.