# Python for in loop to generate dictionary

Tags: python, for-in-loop

I came across this snippet of code, I understand it's a Cartesian product but if someone can break up this line for me `[s+t for s in a for t in b]` from the following code along with docs link for this kind of syntax.

Apparently this `for in` syntax with `s+t`??? is foreign for me and I'm new to python as well. Appreciate docs link so I can understand more about this syntax since there are other variations of for in loops that I'm trying to understand.

```
rows = 'ABCDEFGHI'
cols = '123456789'

def cross(a, b):
    return [s+t for s in a for t in b]

def main():
    print(cross(rows, cols))

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a shorthand syntax known as a list comprehension. See section 5.1.4 of the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

The line is exactly equivalent to this:

```
lst = []
for s in a:
    for t in b:
        lst.append(s+t)
return lst
```

It just finds the sums of every pair of an element in `a` and an element in `b`.

Comment: The output is exactly equivalent, but they're not the same(being pedantic).

Comment: Sure, for example there might be some small performance differences: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108488/are-list-comprehensions-and-functional-functions-faster-than-for-loops

Comment: I actually just finished reading that post to confirm I wasn't talking out of my ass.

Answer (score 1):

It can be broken down into:

```
lst = []
for s in A:
    for t in b:
        lst.append(s+t)
return lst
```

Hope this helps!