# Dynamic Programming for the number of ways of climbing steps

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, memoization, search-tree

The question is to write a function using dynamic programming for the number of ways to climb N steps. Given that only 1 step or 2 steps can be climbed at a time.

For example, if N=3, the function should return [(1,1,1),(1,2),(2,1)]. 
I've written a code in python 3 to calculate. The code is working fine but as N gets as large as 40 it takes the same time or the spyder(Anaconda) application crashes when compared to the same recursive code without using dynamic programming.

Shouldn't it be way more efficient than the normal one?

I've attached the DP code below

```
def stepsdyn(N,memo={}):
    """
    L1 is the list of all possibilities in the left side of the search tree,
    that is with 1 as the last element
    L2 is the list of all possibilities in the right side of the search tree
    memo stores the results of corresponding N
    returns memo[N]
    """
    L1=[]
    L2=[]
    if N==1:
        return [(1,)]
    elif N==0:
        return [()]
    else:
        try:
             return memo[N]
        except:
             for items in stepsdyn(N-1,memo):
                 items+=(1,)
                 L1.append(items)
             for items in stepsdyn(N-2,memo):
                 items+=(2,)
                 L2.append(items)
             memo[N]=L1+L2
             return memo[N]
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it crashes? Is there some error message? Does it just not return anything/take a long time?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Ya it takes a long time and then crashes, that is it gets hanged (Not Responding) and I have to restart my pc. For numbers up to 30 it works fine but takes nearly the same time as the normal recursive code without dynamic programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Basic idea

In computer programming the most basic and common tradeoff is the one between time efficiency and space efficiency. Memoization can be good for time but bad for space and that is the case here. Your program is crashing because that memoization dictionary is holding a lot of data. Right off the bat your recurrence relation means you never need the data that is being held in the `N - 3` spot so you can get rid of it. This somewhat alleviates the memory burden (but not by much).

## Problems/concerns with code

1. Don't memoize values you don't need (see above).
2. Python's handling of mutable default argument means the `memo` dict is only created once. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) for more details. This also means that the dictionary is sitting around (in memory) after the function returns... not good. Generally don't use mutable default arguments unless you have a compelling reason.
3. `list` comprehensions can be [a bit faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108488/are-list-comprehensions-and-functional-functions-faster-than-for-loops) than explicit for loops. More importantly in this case, they are more readable.
4. This last one is more a style thing. You are adding the `1` or the `2` to the tail of the items returned from the recursive call. Typically those elements are added at the head.

## Solutions

#### Same algorithm but more memory and time efficient

```
def stepsdyn_new(N, memo):
    try:
        return memo[N]
    except KeyError:
        l1 = [(1,) + items for items in stepsdyn_new(N - 1, memo)]
        l2 = [(2,) + items for items in stepsdyn_new(N - 2, memo)]
        memo.pop(N - 2)
        memo[N] = l1 + l2
        return memo[N]
```

**Note**: I pass the base cases in as an argument, but you can add the original `if`/`else` if desired.

#### Returning strings

```
def stepsdyn_str(N, memo):
    try:
        return memo[N]
    except KeyError:
        l1 = ['1' + x for x in stepsdyn_str(N - 1, memo)]
        l2 = ['2' + x for x in stepsdyn_str(N - 2, memo)]
        memo.pop(N - 2)
        memo[N] = l1 + l2
        return memo[N]
```

This will return a list of string (e.g. ['111', '12', '21']) instead of a list of tuples. Because each character in a python string only uses 1 byte (instead of the 8 bytes per element in a list/tuple) this yields a lot of memory savings. The result can be converted back to a list of tuples with the following code (though this would incur additional speed/memory penalties):

```
[tuple(map(int, tuple(x))) for x in stepsdyn_str(N, {0: [''], 1: ['1']})]
```

## Efficiency

**Note**: the `steps` function is a non-memoized solution (included below for completeness).

#### Speed

```
|--------------|----------------------------|----------------------------|
|              |           N = 20           |           N = 33           |
|--------------|----------------------------|----------------------------|
| steps        | 47 ms ± 7.34 ms per loop   | 41.2 s ± 1.6 s per loop    |
|--------------|----------------------------|----------------------------|
| stepsdyn     | 10.1 ms ± 1.23 ms per loop | 9.46 s ± 691 ms per loop   |
|--------------|----------------------------|----------------------------|
| stepsdyn_new | 6.74 ms ± 1.03 ms per loop | 7.41 s ± 396 ms per loop   |
|--------------|----------------------------|----------------------------|
| stepsdyn_str | 3.28 ms ± 68.8 µs per loop | 3.67 s ± 121 ms per loop   |
|--------------|----------------------------|----------------------------|
```

Obtained using:

```
%timeit steps(N)
%timeit stepsdyn(N, memo={})
%timeit stepsdyn_new(N, {0: [()], 1: [(1,)]})
%timeit stepsdyn_str(N, {0: [''], 1: ['1']})
```

#### Memory

These estimates are specific to my 16GB memory MBP while evaluating the functions for `N=33`:

- `steps`: 10.8% max memory
- `stepsdyn`: 22.0% max memory
- `stepsdyn_new`: 15.7% max memory
- `stepsdyn_str`: 3.6% max memory

## Non-memoized solution

```
def steps(N):
    if N == 0:
        return [()]
    elif N == 1:
        return [(1,)]
    else:
        l1 = [(1,) + items for items in steps(N - 1)]
        l2 = [(2,) + items for items in steps(N - 2)]
        return l1 + l2
```

Comment: Your code worked well up to numbers like N=35 for which the normal code found it nearly impossible. But still for N=40 the system hangs badly. I'm assuming that such a number still involves a huge set of recursions and it's beyond the scope of what the spyder can do. I thought of increasing the value of N because even for recursive Fibonacci program with dynamic programming, N can take the value of even 120

Comment: @PrashantGovind you may be confusing the calculation of the Nth fibonacci number with creating a list of `fibonacci(N + 1)` elements. Even if you were able to store each element of your list as one bit (that's one bit per `way`), the list for `N = 120` would have 8670007398507948658051921 bits = 1,083,750,924,813,494 gigabytes. The list for N = 40, has 165,580,141 elements in it, where each element is one `way`.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like a succinct way to just count the *number* of ways to climb N steps, given that only 1 step or 2 steps can be climbed at a time, we could implement something like this:

```py
def f(n):
  a, b = 0, 1

  for i in xrange(n):
    a, b = b, a + b

  return b
```

Output:

```py
   f(3)
=> 3
   f(5)
=> 8
   f(40)
=> 165580141
   f(120)
=> 8670007398507948658051921L
```

Notice that the result is simply the `(n + 1)`th [Fibonacci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Use_in_mathematics) number.