# How does this line of code work? (Python, function)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

```
def superindex(string, word):
    return [i for i, ltr in enumerate(string) if ltr == word]
```

I'm a beginner with Python and I would like to know how this look works.

1. How does it create a list?
2. What does `i for i` do?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: It's called a list comprehension

Comment: Please see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)!

Answer (score 3):

It returns the indices where the letter `word` matches a character in the `string` variable.

`for i, ltr in enumerate(string)` is a for loop over the letters in `string`, because you're using enumerate you also get an index `i` as well. However adding the if condition on the end means you only return `i` when the letter `ltr` equals the letter `word`

So this

```
string = "yuppers"
word = "p"
print(superindex(string, word))
```

will return this

`[2,3]`

Answer (score 1):

Would be much easier for you to under stand if it was written like this :

```
lst = []
for i, ltr in enumerate(string):
    if (ltr == word):
        lst.append(i)
```

Comment: Paranthesis around  condition in `if` are unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to understand single-line for loop is using more basic things:

```
>>> l = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> [ltr for ltr in l]
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

For your first question, using square brackets creates a list and it appends the `ltr` value to the list by iterating over the list `l`.

The `enumerate` is a built-in function which allows having a counter while looping over an iterable object. Here, `i` iterates over indexes of the list while `ltr` iterates over the elements of the list `l`. Here is another example:

```
>>> [i for i, ltr in  enumerate(l)]
[0, 1, 2]
>>> [ltr for i, ltr in  enumerate(l)]
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Additioanlly, you have a condition at the end:

```
>>>[ltr for i, ltr in  enumerate(l) if i>0]
['b', 'c']
```

Here, it only takes the elements of the list `l` with indexes greater than `0`.

I hope, this helps understanding the concepts :)

Answer (score 0):

This function is creating a list of the `ltr` indexes of an iterable variable `string`, that match the object `word`

This function can be written in a simpler way:

```
    def superindex(string, word):
        l = list()
        for i, ltr in enumerate(string):
            if ltr == word: # check if ltr is equal to the variable word
                l.append(i) # append the index i of the matching ltr in the string
        return l
```

`enumerate`

- The enumerate function allows us to loop over something and have an automatic counter
- Here each 'ltr' in the variable 'string' is assigned a number 'i' (starting from zero)

`[i for i...`

- In the original version of the function, the `for` loop is written as a pythonic list comprehension. This allows us to loop over an iterable and create a list in one line of code (e.g. `[i for i in string]`). There are many cases where this form of a list is more efficient (see [Are list-comprehensions and functional functions faster than "for loops"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108488/are-list-comprehensions-and-functional-functions-faster-than-for-loops))

This function will work on letters:
`superindex('foo', 'o')`
returns `[1,2]`

and also lists of words:
`superindex(['foo', 'bar'], 'bar')`
returns `[1]`

Note: Although the variables suggest this is applicable to string and words, a more appropriate naming might be (`list_of_strings` and `word`) or (`string` and `letter`). If a more general case was sought maybe (`iterable` and `template`)...