# Using a for loop vs list comprehension to optimise code

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, list-comprehension

Why is the almost_all_a more efficient than almost_all_b which utilizes a for loop vs using list comprehension? Surely they are both O(n)?
EDIT: The answers in the other question are non specific and basically say one can be faster than the other depending on the case. So then what about this case?

```
def almost_all_a(numbers):
    sumall = sum(numbers)
    rangelen = range(len(numbers))
    return [sumall - numbers[i] for i in rangelen]

def almost_all_b(numbers):
    sumall = sum(numbers)
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        numbers[i] = sumall - numbers[i]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108488/are-list-comprehensions-and-functional-functions-faster-than-for-loops

Comment: Hi thanks for that I'm still getting used to stack overflow but I still can't see how in this case the list iteration is more efficient? The second algorithm is failing the test for larger lists.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the related question contained everything, but it was somehow hidden.

Let us look at what `almost_all_a`: it builds a new list of the same size as the original list and then returns that new list. For a large list, this will use twice the memory required by the list (assuming lists of numbers here). And is you call the function that way: `nums = almost_all_a(nums)`, you are just building a new list and when done discard the previous one. Two performance impacts: requires (temporary) memory, and requires the garbage collector to clean up the old list.

In `almost_all_b` nothing of that happens: you are just changing the list element in place: no extra allocation (memory gain) and nothing to collect (execution time gain).

TL/DR: what makes `a` version lose, it that it boils down to allocating a new list, while the [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22108640/3545273) said:

> Using a list comprehension in place of a loop that doesn't build a list, nonsensically accumulating a list of meaningless values and then throwing the list away, is often slower because of the overhead of creating and extending the list.

Answer (score 1):

Your complexity analysis is correct: `n` operations to compute the sum plus `n` operations to compute the list in both cases makes `O(n)`.

But before we talk about speed, you surely have noticed that `almost_all_b` has a side-effect whereas `almost_all_a` is side-effect free. Worse, `almost_all_b` is not idempotent. If you call repeatedly `almost_all_b`, the argument `numbers` will be modified each time. **Unless you have a very good reason, you should prefer `almost_all_a` to `almost_all_b` since is easier to understand and less error prone**.

## Benchmark 1

I will try to confirm your assertion (*`almost_all_a` [is] more efficient than `almost_all_b`*) with `timeit`:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> ns=list(range(100))
>>> timeit(lambda: almost_all_a(ns), number=10000)
0.06381335399782984
>>> timeit(lambda: almost_all_b(ns), number=10000)
2.3228586789991823
```

Wow! `almost_all_a` is roughly 35 times faster than `almost_all_b`!!! No. That was a joke. You can see what happened: `almost_all_b` was applied 10000 times to `[1,...,90]` with the side-effect, hence the numbers grew insanely:

```
>>> len(str(ns[0])) # number of digits of the first element!
19959
```

Ok, that was just to convince you to avoid functions with side effects.

## Benchmark 2

Now, the real test:

```
>>> timeit('ns=list(range(100));almost_all(ns)', globals={'almost_all':almost_all_a})
5.720672591000039
>>> timeit('ns=list(range(100));almost_all(ns)', globals={'almost_all':almost_all_b})
5.937547881
```

Note that the benchmark might give different results with another list or on another platform. (Think of what will happen if the list takes 90 % of the available RAM.) But let's assume that we can generalize.

## Python bytecode

Let's look at the bytecode:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(almost_all_a)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (sum)
              2 LOAD_DEREF               0 (numbers)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 STORE_DEREF              1 (sumall)

  3           8 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (range)
             10 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (len)
             12 LOAD_DEREF               0 (numbers)
             14 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 STORE_FAST               1 (rangelen)

  4          20 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (numbers)
             22 LOAD_CLOSURE             1 (sumall)
             24 BUILD_TUPLE              2
             26 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object <listcomp> at 0x7fdc551dee40, file "<stdin>", line 4>)
             28 LOAD_CONST               2 ('almost_all_a.<locals>.<listcomp>')
             30 MAKE_FUNCTION            8
             32 LOAD_FAST                1 (rangelen)
             34 GET_ITER
             36 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             38 RETURN_VALUE
```

And:

```
>>> dis.dis(almost_all_b)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (sum)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (numbers)
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (sumall)

  3           8 SETUP_LOOP              36 (to 46)
             10 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (range)
             12 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (len)
             14 LOAD_FAST                0 (numbers)
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             20 GET_ITER
        >>   22 FOR_ITER                20 (to 44)
             24 STORE_FAST               2 (i)

  4          26 LOAD_FAST                1 (sumall)
             28 LOAD_FAST                0 (numbers)
             30 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             32 BINARY_SUBSCR
             34 BINARY_SUBTRACT
             36 LOAD_FAST                0 (numbers)
             38 LOAD_FAST                2 (i)
             40 STORE_SUBSCR
             42 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           22
        >>   44 POP_BLOCK
        >>   46 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             48 RETURN_VALUE
```

The beginning is almost the same. Then, you have a list comprehension that is like a black box. If we open the box, we see:

```
>>> dis.dis(almost_all_a.__code__.co_consts[1])
  4           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (.0)
        >>    4 FOR_ITER                16 (to 22)
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (i)
              8 LOAD_DEREF               1 (sumall)
             10 LOAD_DEREF               0 (numbers)
             12 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             14 BINARY_SUBSCR
             16 BINARY_SUBTRACT
             18 LIST_APPEND              2
             20 JUMP_ABSOLUTE            4
        >>   22 RETURN_VALUE
```

You have two differences:

- in the list comprehension, `sumall` and `numbers` are loaded with `LOAD_DEREF` and not `LOAD_FAST` (that's normal for a closure) and should be a little slower;
- in the list comprehension, `LIST_APPEND` replaces the assignment to `numbers[i]` (`LOAD_FAST(numbers)/LOAD_FAST(i)/STORE_SUBSCR` at lines 36-40).

My guess is that the overhead comes from that assignement.

## Another benchmark

You can rewrite `almost_all_a` to be even neater, because you don't need the index:

```
def almost_all_c(numbers):
    sumall = sum(numbers)
    return [sumall - n for n in numbers]
```

This version is faster (on my example + platform) than `almost_all_a`:

```
>>> timeit('ns=list(range(100));almost_all(ns)', globals={'almost_all':almost_all_a})
5.755438814000172
>>> timeit('ns=list(range(100));almost_all(ns)', globals={'almost_all':almost_all_b})
5.93645353099987
>>> timeit('ns=list(range(100));almost_all(ns)', globals={'almost_all':almost_all_c})
4.571863283000084
```

(Note that, as often in Python, the neater version is the fastest.) The difference between `almost_all_a` and `almost_all_c` is the use of the access to the `i`-th item of `numbers` (you can decompile `almost_all_c` of you want to check).

## Conlusion

I seems that the bottleneck here is the access to the `i`-th item of `numbers`:

- one time in `almost_all_a`;
- two times in `almost_all_b`;
- never in `almost_all_c`.

That's why `almost_all_a` is faster than `almost_all_b`.