# Alternative/faster ways of creating arrays in python 2.7

Tags: python, arrays

I have the following code to create an array:

```
    for i in range(channel_count):
        if not result[i] is None:
            result[i] = array('f', result[i])

    return result
```

Is there any other faster way to create arrays in python 2.7, so it takes less time to execute the code.

Comment: list comprehension?

Comment: There are no arrays in Python

Comment: Faster as in "takes less time to type out the code", or "takes less time to execute the code"?

Comment: @Alderven, there are no arrays in the builtin namespace, but there is a built-in `array` module which defines an `array` type.

Comment: @Alderven There is. `array` is a builtin module :)

Comment: @Kevin, takes less time to execute the code.

Comment: @alec_djinn, I've never heard of list comprehension before, thank you for the advice, I'll have a look at it! I'm not very experienced in python.

Comment: Either list comprehension or a simple for loop, if you are beginner in python, as my answer below

Comment: Didn't know about that. Thanks Kevin & han solo.

Comment: Caveat emptor on answers involving list comps - while they are more concise, they aren't _much_ faster than the longhand "create an empty list, then append to it in a loop" approach. Related reading: [Are list-comprehensions and functional functions faster than “for loops”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22108488/953482)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define an empty list and use list's append function to append the result to it when the condition holds true

```
result_arr = []
for i in range(channel_count):
    if not result[i] is None:
        result_arr.append(result[i])
return result
```

Or list comprehension can be used

```
result_arr = [r for r in result if not r is None]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by comprehensive way by follow.

```
output_array = [c if not c is None for c in range(channel_count)]
```

You can find more information on [List comrehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) from [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)