# I want to select an element from a list which acts as a key in a dictionary whose value is minimum.How can this be done(see below)?

Tags: python-3.x, list, min

There is a situation where i have to find the element in a list whose corresponding value in a dictionary is minimum.

So here "boxes" is a list and "values" is a dictionary.

I have tried the following and this seems to work,

```
minvalue = 10
for box in boxes:
    if len(values[box]) > 1:
        if len(values[box]) < minvalue:
            minvalue = len(values[box])
            bestbox = box
```

But this is another way of doing the same thing but i don't get this line of code

```
n, s = min((len(values[s]), s) for s in boxes if len(values[s]) > 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking at is called **List comprehensions**. [They are not necessarily efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22108640/7841468) but the community prefers since it looks pythonic.

Your list comprehension typically has 3 parts :

```
new_list = [expression for_loop_one_or_more conditions]
```

So the ***first part*** you see `min((len(values[s]), s)` is an expression which on evaluation yields `min()` value.This is going to feed your for loop that follows next.

The ***second part*** is the `for` loop which gets its iterating value for `s` from the ***first part***

Knowing this far will give you an understanding of the `if condition` where it compares the current iterating value of `s` at the index of `list`  `values`