# Using a list comprehension for returning first found element or None

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to optimize my python code and I thougt I could improve the following for loop with a list comprehension to increase performance:

```
for obj in self.objs:
    if obj.is_runnable():
        return obj
return None
```

My idea was to do something like this:

```
objs = [obj for obj in self.objs if obj.is_runnable()]
return objs[0]
```

But I think this wouldn't be better, beacuse it does not stop iteration after the first found element and for now it doesn't handle the `None` case, but this could be avoided with an `if-else` statement.
My question: Is there a way, tou use a list comprehension, which breaks, after it returns the first element?

Comment: You should take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22108640/1506086 - TLDR, list comprehensions likely aren't faster than a loop where the loop wasn't creating or appending to a list in the first place.

Comment: Also note that your current implementation is the proper idiomatic one - it's correct, clear, simple, obvious, and very easy to trace. Hint 1: don't try to be clever, hint 2: don't try to optimize code that is not _proven_ (using a profiler) to have performance issues (nb: I don't mean "write stupid and inefficiant code", just "keep it as simple and obvious as possible"), hint 3: real optimizations usually require using another data structure and algorithm (and/or in the case of Python rewritting the critical parts in C or using a lib that already provide one or both of those strategies)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I have this in mind, but thanks for clairification. I knew, that the code snippet took long, I didn't know, if the `is_runnable` method took long or the for loop. Indeed it was the `is_runnable' call, because I was accessing an pandas dataframe row in a slow way, but I think, there is a reason for generator expressions and list comprehensions, so why don't use it?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX profiling would have shown you where the issue was. And well, yes, there are very good reasons for generator expressions etc, but your case is definitly NOT part of those reasons (IMHO etc). "Why don't use it" ? Quite simply because the solution in the answer you accepted is nowhere as simple, obvious, readable and maintainable as your original implementation. Been here (20+ years experience), done that (trying to be the smart guy by using all the bells and whistles), and finally [reached enlightenment](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). But YMMV of course ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers no,  I am new to programming. Programmed in C++ for 3 years and now learning python, but one of the first things I heard about python is, is to avoid loops when I can. So I thougt this would be the "python-way-to-go"

Comment: Well, this is just another misunderstood advice used out of context I'm afraid.  As mentionned by Rob Streeting in the very first comment, list comprehensions (as well as `filter` or `map` etc) are only faster for _some_ cases (and even then readabilty still matters).

Comment: wrt/ generator expressions (and other lazy iterables), the point is mostly lazy evaluation (avoiding useless computations and memory use).  Now no one will kill you for using tobias's solution - but a junior dev will have a hard time understanding it, and even a seasonned python programmer will need a bit more time to get it than your initial version - perhaps a split second, but when trying to debug a deeply nested issue even a split second of useless distraction is a PITA.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) with a default value:

```
return next((obj for obj in self.objs if obj.is_runnable()), None)
```

Note that I changed the list comprehension `[...]` to a generator expression `(...)`, otherwise you would still create the entire list before getting the first element. With `(...)`, it will only test as many elements as needed.

Or with `filter`, where `ClassOfObj` is a placeholder for the class of `obj`:

```
return next(filter(ClassOfObj.is_runnable, self.objs), None)
```

Comment: what do you mean by placeholder? The class name? I can't get it running with the filter approach

Comment: @RoQuOTriX You have to pass a reference to the method to `filter`. Since it is a method of that object, you have to pass it in the form `ClassName.method`. But you can just as well use the first version.

Comment: Does this `next`approach have a name I can search for like list-comprehension?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX `next` is a builtin function (see provided link) and the `(...)` in contrast to `[...]` is called a generator expression.

Comment: I've got the error: module 'ObjClass' has not attribute 'is_runnable'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @RoQuOTriX To answer this, I'd have to see more of you code, in particular the actual class and probably also how you create the list. But as I said, you can just use the first version.

Comment: Ok, then I use the first solution. The second seemed "cleaner" to me. I think the error has something to do with the way I import my modules