# Check if list of file paths exist

Tags: python, list

I have a list of file paths. I need to check which of the files in the list exist and which are not. I want to delete the paths that do not exist. I know i can use os.path.exists() or os.path.isfile() but for these I need to run a for loop and check each path in the list. Is there a better way to do this in python?

Comment: whats wrong with for loop now?

Comment: nothing's wrong with for loop i just want to know if there is another way. I dont know why would you downvote for that.

Comment: if you're worried about performance, maybe just check the existence of a path right before you use it. unless you need to make sure that ALL of paths exist before you execute any code, to avoid half-deployed stuff. 

maybe look into list comprehensions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108488/are-list-comprehensions-and-functional-functions-faster-than-for-loops

Comment: Are all of the paths in the same folder?

Comment: yes all the paths are in the same folder.

Comment: You need to define "better" here. What is it you want to improve on the solution you already seem to have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all paths are within the same folder you can retrieve all files that exist in the folder in one call to [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) then you can use [set operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) to get all paths in your list that exist in the 
directory

```
files_in_dir = set(os.listdir(PATH))
existing_files = set(your_list_of_files) & files_in_dir
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are trying to delete the files from the list not from the os

You can do this with a list comprehension:

```
files = [...] # list of file paths

files = [path for path in files if os.path.exists(path)]
```

Comment: If the OP is worried about performance, then set is likely to be a bit more performant than a list - especially if their are many paths to check.