# Parsing XML: find element sub-tree without a loop

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I am parsing an XML payload using [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). I cannot share the exact code or file as it shares sensitive information. I am able to successfully extract the information I need by iterating through an element (as seen in the ElementTree documentation) and appending the output to lists. For example:

```
list_col_name = []
list_col_value = []

for col in root.iter('my_table'):
    # get col name
    col_name = col.find('col_name').text
    list_col_name.append(col_name
    # get col value
    col_value = col.find('col_value').text
    list_col_value.append(col_value)
```

I can now put these into a dictionary and proceed with the remainder of what needs to be done:

```
dict_ = dict(zip(list_col_name, list_col_value))
```

However, I need this to happen as quickly as possible and am wondering if there is a way in which I can extract `list_col_name` at once (i.e., using `findall()` or something like that). Just curious as to way to increase the speed of xml parsing if possible. All answers/recommendations are appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

My proposal is to use "incremental" parsing of the source file,
based on *iterparse* method. The reason is that you actually:

- don't need any full parsed XML tree,
- during incremental parsing you can discard processed elements,
  so the need for memory is also smaller.

Another hint is to use *lxml* library, instead of *ElementTree*.
The reason is that although *iterparse* method exists in **both** these
libraries, but the *lxml* version has additional *tag* parameter, so you
are able to "limit" the loop to processing the tags of interest only.

As the source file I used (something like):

```
<root>
  <my_table id="t1">
    <col_name>N1</col_name>
    <col_value>V1</col_value>
    <some_other_stuff>xx1</some_other_stuff>
  </my_table>
  <my_table id="t2">
    <col_name>N2</col_name>
    <col_value>V2</col_value>
    <some_other_stuff>xx1</some_other_stuff>
  </my_table>
  <my_table id="t3">
    <col_name>N3</col_name>
    <col_value>V3</col_value>
    <some_other_stuff>xx1</some_other_stuff>
  </my_table>
</root>
```

Actually, my source file:

- includes *9* `my_table` element (not *3*),
- `some_other_stuff` is repeated 8 times (in each `my_table`), to
  simulate other elements contained in each `my_table`.

I performed 3 tests, using *%timeit*:

1. Your loop, with prepended parsing of the source XML file:

   ```
   from lxml import etree as et

   def fn1():
       root = et.parse('Tables.xml')
       list_col_name = []
       list_col_value = []
       for col in root.iter('my_table'):
           col_name = col.find('col_name').text
           list_col_name.append(col_name)
           col_value = col.find('col_value').text
           list_col_value.append(col_value)
       return dict(zip(list_col_name, list_col_value))
   ```

   The execution time was 1.74 ms.
2. My loop, based on *iterparse*, processing only the "required" elements:

   ```
   def fn2():
       key = ''
       dict_ = {}
       context = et.iterparse('Tables.xml', tag=['my_table', 'col_name', 'col_value'])
       for action, elem in context:
           tag = elem.tag
           txt = elem.text
           if tag == 'col_name':
               key = txt
           elif tag == 'col_value':
               dict_[key] = txt
           elif tag == 'my_table':
               elem.clear()
               elem.getparent().remove(elem)
       return dict_
   ```

   I assume that in each *my_table* element *col_name* occurs **before**
   *col_value* and each *my_table* contains only one child named *col_name*
   and *col_value*.

   Note also that the above function clears each *my_table* element and
   removes it from the parsed XML tree (*getparent* function is available
   only in *lxml* version).

   Another improvement is that I "directly" add each *key* / *value* pair
   to the dictionary to be returned by this function, so no *zip* is needed.

   The execution time is 1.33 ms. Not very much quicker, but at least some
   time gain is visible.
3. You can also read all *col_name* and *col_value* elements, calling
   *findall* and then call *zip*:

   ```
   def fn3():
       root = et.parse('Tables.xml')
       list_col_name = []
       for elem in root.findall('.//col_name'):
           list_col_name.append(elem.text)
       list_col_value = []
       for elem in root.findall('.//col_value'):
           list_col_value.append(elem.text)
       return dict(zip(list_col_name, list_col_value))
   ```

   The execution time is 1.38 ms. Also something quicker that your original
   solution, but no significant difference to my first solution (*fn2*).

Of course, the final result heavily depends on:

- the size of your input file,
- how much "other stuff" contains each *my_table* element.

Answer (score 2):

Consider list comprehension with `findall` to avoid list initialization/append and explicit `for` loop which may [marginally improve performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22108488/1422451):

```
# FINDALL LIST COMPREHENSION
list_col_name = [e.text for e in root.findall('./my_table/col_name')]
list_col_value = [e.text for e in root.findall('./my_table/col_value')]

dict(zip(list_col_name, list_col_value))
```

Alternatively, with `lxml` (third-party library) that fully supports XPath 1.0, consider [`xpath()`](https://lxml.de/1.3/xpathxslt.html#xpath) that can assign parsing output directly to lists also avoiding initialization/append and `for` loop:

```
import lxml.etree as et
...

# XPATH LISTS
list_col_name = root.xpath('my_table/col_name/text()')
list_col_value = root.xpath('my_table/col_value/text()')

dict(zip(list_col_name, list_col_value))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's anything you want.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
ranks = doc.selects('country>(rank>text())')
print (ranks)
ranks = doc.selects('country>rank()')
print (ranks)
ranks = doc.selects('country>children()')
print (ranks)
```

Result:

```
['1', '4', '68']
[{'tag': 'rank', 'html': '1'}, {'tag': 'rank', 'html': '4'}, {'tag': 'rank', 'html': '68'}]
[[{'tag': 'rank', 'html': '1'}, {'tag': 'year', 'html': '2008'}, {'tag': 'gdppc', 'html': '141100'}, {'name': 'Austria', 'direction': 'E', 'tag': 'neighbor'}, {'name': 'Switzerland', 'direction': 'W', 'tag': 'neighbor'}], [{'tag': 'rank', 'html': '4'}, {'tag': 'year', 'html': '2011'}, {'tag': 'gdppc', 'html': '59900'}, {'name': 'Malaysia', 'direction': 'N', 'tag': 'neighbor'}], [{'tag': 'rank', 'html': '68'}, {'tag': 'year', 'html': '2011'}, {'tag': 'gdppc', 'html': '13600'}, {'name': 'Costa Rica', 'direction': 'W', 'tag': 'neighbor'}, {'name': 'Colombia', 'direction': 'E', 'tag': 'neighbor'}]]
```

Here are more examples:https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples