# optimization of for loops

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Is there a way to optimize the code below ?

data, train_data are dataframe 
data has almost 1M rows

```
timesteps = 20
for i in range (0, len(data)):
    for j in range (0, timesteps):
        train_data = train_data.append(data.iloc[i], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108488/are-list-comprehensions-and-functional-functions-faster-than-for-loops

Comment: How are you using *j*? Also, using `DataFrame.append` in a for-loop leads to inefficient [quadratic copying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489724/1422451).

Comment: apparently by using numpy performance could increase. Someone could help by writing an equivalent code using numpy ?