# Whats the fastes way to delete objects with specific atributes from a list

Tags: python, list, performance, class

This is what I have come up with but it feels really clunky
and it has to be the slow solution.

```python
class classNameHere(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.value = number

classes = [classNameHere(i) for i in range(1000)]

print(len(classes))

pos = 0

while pos <= len(classes)-1:
    if classes[pos].value % 2:
        del(classes[pos])
    else:
        pos += 1
        
print(len(classes))
```

Comment: This will cause some problems.don't operate the list while iterate it.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA Given that `pos` is only incremented when nothing is removed from the list, then this technically does not cause issues

Comment: @vallentin In some specific circumstance. If he want to remove some consecutive elements,that will cause this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
class classNameHere(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.value = number

classes = [classNameHere(i) for i in range(1000)]
classes = [pos for pos in classes if not pos.value % 2]

print(len(classes))
```

Output:

```
500
```

Comment: OMG that's 100 times nicer. I didn't know you could put if statements into list comprehensions. That opens op so many doors. Are list comprehensions fast?

Comment: @TheDopplerEffect, this post should answer you question [`Are list comprehensions fast?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108488/are-list-comprehensions-and-functional-functions-faster-than-for-loops)