# apply function repeatedly in python without loops

Tags: python, iterator, functools

I have a python function that I'd like to apply to a value many, many times. I know I can do it with a for loop:

```
for i in range(N_iter):
    val=f(val)
```

But is there a more efficient way, maybe using itertools or functools?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are list-comprehensions and functional functions faster than "for loops"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108488/are-list-comprehensions-and-functional-functions-faster-than-for-loops)

Comment: How would one write this as a list comprehension?

Comment: You can try multithreading (https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) assuming the function is thread safe.

Comment: @Mike67 How do you multithread something as inherently sequential as this?

Comment: I'm more interested in a single threaded solution. Also, how would it work since iteration (i) depends on iteration (i-1)?

Comment: If you want low runtime instead of succinct expression, then the standard tips regarding function local variables and unrolling apply.

Comment: I can't think of a way this can be sped up in the general case.  Mostly vectorization/GPU compute can be used for acceleration, but I don't see how these can help in the general case.

Comment: If the problem lends itself, memoization might be useful... but that's not very general.

Comment: @thatotherguy can you explain what you mean by local variables and unrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's at least two things you can do: use local variables and unroll the loop.

Here's the baseline:

```
def f(x):
  return x+1

N_iter=16777216
val=0
for i in range(N_iter):
    val=f(val)
print(val)
```

On my system, this takes about `0m2.448s`.

Here's the code when all references are local, meaning that Python won't have to load and store them each time:

```
def f(x):
  return x+1

def iterate(f, N_iter, val):
  for i in range(N_iter):
      val=f(val)
  print(val)

iterate(f, 16777216, 0)
```

This takes `0m1.648s`.

You can also manually unroll the loop, doing more iterations per jump. Here's 8 (for simplicity it doesn't handle remainders):

```
def f(x):
  return x+1

def iterate(f, N_iter, val):
  for i in range(N_iter//8):
      val=f(val)
      val=f(val)
      val=f(val)
      val=f(val)
      val=f(val)
      val=f(val)
      val=f(val)
      val=f(val)
  print(val)

iterate(f, 16777216, 0)
```

This takes `0m1.327s`.

Together, they've sped up this tight loop up by nearly 50%.

When you reach this level of microoptimization, it may be worth rethinking the whole approach or rewriting in a faster language.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about these tricks. You're right though, another language would be better, or using Numba.

Answer (score -2):

Call the function recursively, Set a base condition that gets decremented in every call. cheers

Comment: Do you think that will be more efficient? Why?

Comment: Though memoization makes recursion useful, however, iterative based methods are always faster. I mistook the question for space efficiency.