# Use of numpy.select when conditions and hence choices are too many

Tags: python, numpy, loops, if-statement

I have just started using `numpy.select()` given specific conditions and choices list.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
conditions = [
    data['column_name'].values == mylist[0],
    data['column_name'].values == mylist[1],
    data['column_name'].values == mylist[2],
    data['column_name'].values == mylist[3],
    data['column_name'].values == mylist[4],
    data['column_name'].values == mylist[5],
    data['column_name'].values == mylist[6]
] 

    choices = [
    data['column_name'].multiply(data['xyz'])*mylist[0]*Price/another_list[0],
    data['column_name'].multiply(data['xyz'])*mylist[1]*Price/another_list[1],
    data['column_name'].multiply(data['xyz'])*mylist[2]*Price/another_list[2],
    data['column_name'].multiply(data['xyz'])*mylist[3]*Price/another_list[3],
    data['column_name'].multiply(data['xyz'])*mylist[4]*Price/another_list[4],
    data['column_name'].multiply(data['xyz'])*mylist[5]*Price/another_list[5],
    data['column_name'].multiply(data['xyz'])*mylist[6]*Price/another_list[6]
]

outcome = np.select(conditions, choices)
```

What I am trying to find out, is what if I had say 30 conditions and 30 different choices? Do I have to fill `conditions` and `choices` lists manually? Is there any shortcut similar to the one below?

```
conditions = [data['column_name'].values == mylist]

choices = [data['column_name'].multiply(data['xyz'])*mylist*Price/another_list]

outcome = np.select(conditions, choices)
```

I hope I passed the message, looking forward to your ideas. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to manually add it.

```
conditions = [data['column_name'].values == i for i in mylist]
choices = [data['column_name'].multiply(data['xyz'])*i*Price/j for i,j in zip(mylist,another_list)]
outcome = np.select(conditions, choices)
```

This will add conditions and choices automatically for all the elements. Also, if you don't want it over all the elements then can use slices like mylist[:limit] or mylist[::2](even positions) etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this seems to be a list comprehension right?  Do you think this will reduce speed of execution?

Comment: Yes its a list comprehension

Comment: Its speed is faster than equivalent  'for' loop . according to the https://stackoverflow.com/a/22108640/14337775.

Comment: If this answer was useful then please upvote/accept it.

Comment: apologies, but my score does not allow for a +1 I have upvoted anyways though. Hope this helps.

Comment: ohh, This is strange!!   You should be able to upvote/downvote/accept the answer as you have asked the question.

Comment: Also, when you ask and accept an answer then you get 'scholar' badge. You should be able to get that.

Comment: The pop up message when I click says: “ Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less 15 reputation are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score.”  Maybe try and upvote my Question so that I reach 15 ? Don’t know i am just trying to help.

Comment: You can try now.

Comment: If you want then you may also accept this answer to get scholar badge.