# Vectorized way to find first occurrence per row

Tags: python, pandas, performance, vectorization

I have two Pandas DataFrames df_x and df_y. df_x has two columns 'high target' and 'low target'. Per every row of df_x, I would like to search through the instances of df_y and see whether the 'high target' was reached before the 'low target'. Currently, I implemented the above using .apply. However, my code is too inefficient as it linearly scales with the number of rows in df_x. Any suggestions to optimize/vectorize my code?

[image: df_x]

[image: df_y]

```
def efficient_high_after_low(row, minute_df):
    """True, if high happened after the low, else False.
    Args:
        row: A pandas dataframe
             with high, low,
        minute_df: the whole dataframe
    """

    minute_df_after = minute_df.loc[row.period_end_idx+pd.Timedelta(minutes=1):]
    #print(minute_df_after)
    first_highs = (minute_df_after.ge(row['high target']))
    first_lows = (minute_df_after.le(row['low target']))
    
    hi_sum, lo_sum = first_highs.sum(), first_lows.sum()
    if (len(first_highs) != len(first_lows)):
        raise Exception('Unequal length of first_highs and first_lows')
    else:
        if ((len(first_highs) == 0)):
            return None
    
        elif ((hi_sum == 0) & (lo_sum != 0)):
            return True
        elif ((hi_sum != 0) & (low_sum == 0)):
            return False
        elif ((hi_sum == 0) & (low_sum == 0)):
            return None 
        elif (first_highs.idxmax() > first_lows.idxmax()):
            return True
        elif(first_highs.idxmax() < first_lows.idxmax()):
            return False
        else:
            return None
```

And I do the following to get these boolean values:

```
df_x.apply(efficient_high_after_low, axis=1, args=(df_y['open'],))
```

Running the code above on the first 1000 lines takes 4 seconds.

Comment: all sum operations can be done 1 time, assign to a variable and use them in the algorithm 
`hi_sum = (first_highs).sum()` `low_sum = (first_lows).sum()`

Comment: @Glauco Thanks, made the change. The overhead is from applying the function to every row, so the above change does not change the run time significantly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **Solution 1** (Iterative):

```
def high_after_low(high_targets, 
                   low_targets, 
                   vals, 
                   dic):

    """True, if the high target was hit before low; else, False.
    Args:
        high_target: A NumPy array, the high targets 
                                of each row.
        low_target: A NumPy array, the low targets 
                                of each row.
        vals: A NumPy array, the current values
        dic: A dictionary; maps every row of the targets to the open values.
            
    Returns:
        high_after_low: A pandas series with True, False, and None values per row.
        Meaning of each value:
            True: the timeseries hit high after low (or low was never hit)
            False: the timeseries hit high before low (or high was never hit)
            None: (1) neither low or high were hit, (2) low and high were hit 
                    at the same row
    """

    dic_keys = list(dic.keys())
    size = len(dic_keys)
    
    high_hit_rows = [(((a).argmax()+dic[i] ) if((a:= (vals[dic[i]:] 
                    >= high_target[i])).any()) else np.nan ) for i in range(size)]
    low_hit_rows  = [(((b).argmax()+dic[i]) if((b:= (vals[dic[i]:] 
                    <= low_target[i])).any()) else np.nan ) for i in range(size)]
    
    high_hit_rows = np.array(high_hit_rows, dtype=np.float32)
    low_hit_rows = np.array(low_hit_rows, dtype=np.float32)

    high_after_low = np.empty((size))
    
    high_after_low[:] = np.nan

    high_after_low[np.isnan(low_hit_rows) & (~np.isnan(high_hit_rows))] = False
    high_after_low[(~np.isnan(low_hit_rows)) & np.isnan(high_hit_rows)] = True
    high_after_low[((~np.isnan(low_hit_rows)) & (~np.isnan(high_hit_rows)) 
                    & (low_hit_rows < high_hit_rows))] = True
    high_after_low[((~np.isnan(low_hit_rows)) & (~np.isnan(high_hit_rows)) 
                    & (low_hit_rows > high_hit_rows))] = False
    
    return high_after_low
```

## **Solution 1** (Vectorized):

The vectorized solution requires pre-processing of the input array. We need to pre-process the input array into a 2d array such that the i-th row contains the array's values from [i:i+T]. Then,

```
def vectorized_high_after_low(df, high_values, low_values):
    """Args:
       df: A pandas DataFrame, containing each value per row. Each column contains the values or row i, t rows ahead.
       high_values: The high targets corresponding to each row
       low_values: The low targets corresponding to each row.
    """
    higher = (df.ge(high_values)).idxmax(axis=1)
    lower = (df.le(low_values)).idxmax(axis=1)

    higher[higher==0] = df.shape[1]
    lower[lower==0] = df.shape[1]
    high_after_low = higher < lower
    high_after_low[higher==lower] = np.nan
    
    return high_after_low
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you could do:

First of all put the `open` column in your main dataframe, let's call it `df` (note: this only works if you have the exact same index on `df_y`, if you don't, consider other solutions like [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) or [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html?highlight=pa))

```
df = df_x
df["open"] = df_y["open"]
```

I also took the liberty of [renaming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11346337/4713169) your columns.

As long as your timeseries index is ordered, we can reset the index with

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

---

So now we have `df` something like this (values are made up):

```
   high_trgt    low_trgt    open
0   8.746911    8.712824    9.243329
1   9.472977    10.190079   9.744083
2   9.445111    10.269676   9.859353
3   9.972061    10.014381   9.132204
4   8.934692    8.914729    11.453276

# You "time" column isn't actually necessary for this solution
```

We can create a *map* of where the targets have been hit

```
map_high = df.open.values >= df.high_trgt.values
map_low = df.open.values <= df.low_trgt.values
```

Now the resource intensive bit:

```
df["high_was_hit_on"] = pd.Series([map_high[i+1:].argmax() for i in range(len(map_high)-1)])
df["low_was_hit_on"] = pd.Series([map_low[i+1:].argmax() for i in range(len(map_low)-1)])
```

Output:

```
    high_trgt   low_trgt    open        high_was_hit_on low_was_hit_on
0   8.746911    8.712824    9.243329    0               0
1   9.472977    10.190079   9.744083    0               3
2   9.445111    10.269676   9.859353    0               2
3   9.972061    10.014381   9.132204    1               1
4   8.934692    8.914729    11.453276   0               0
```

What I did here is iterating over the **range** of the columns, and just checking where the highest value (hence, *index*) **starting from that row** is in the *map* that we created before.

Now we can easily check which happened first by doing:

```
# Here you can customize what you need the results to be
# when two hits happen at the same time
df["high_after_low"] = df.high_was_hit_on < df.low_was_hit_on
```

---

In terms of speed, this is the test over a `df` with 1M rows:

```
%timeit find_first_hit(df)
3.46 s ± 253 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

Truth be told, this isn't exactly *vectorized*, but I can't think of anything that you could do to really achieve that here. Hope that my solution is helpful anyway.

Comment: I need to write test units to confirm, but I think this could work. Do you know why this is more efficient than the method I used? They both rely on looping through the range of the columns.

Comment: I think there are a few reason why my code is faster: first of all I'm using vectorization as much as I can, while you have a lot of logic going on in your function, that probably adds a lot of overhead on every loop. Also, [list comprehension are implemented in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22108488/4713169), so they are really fast and probably faster than the `apply` method, which is pretty much just a thin veil over a normal for loop. Also, using `int`s in the looping probably helps.

Comment: Thanks, any suggestions for taking care of the edge cases efficiently? if the maps are all false, I want to return None for the given row. argmax() returns the first index if they are all False.

Comment: You can be creative with the edge cases as you can handle them after the resource intensive process happens, so you don't need to worry about being ultra-efficient. You can use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) or [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)  to determine what value to choose based on the condition. Just be careful about when the targets are **never** hit.

Comment: right, they are **never** hit if the `maps[i+1:].argmax()` is an all `False` array, in which I need to return None. I think I can only take care of that inside the loop though.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry. Yes, you could try something like `[(map_high[i+1:].argmax() if map_high[i+1:].any() else None) for i in range(len(map_high)-1)]`; it should work but I haven't tested it yet. (Naturally this is only for `map_high`, it's just the same for `map_low`)

Comment: it adds about 42% overhead, but still **MUCH** faster than my original solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245237/discussion-between-965311532-and-vanillihoot).