# Why is Python any( pred for _ in _ ) much faster than for loop

Tags: python, profiling, any

This question is very similar to: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108488/are-list-comprehensions-and-functional-functions-faster-than-for-loops), but I couldn't find the answer there.

```
# 0m2.676s
#
# note that it should be == instead of in
# but as far as timing goes, it would be even faster
# (thanks to @Booboo for pointing this)
#
# here: ------------++
#                   ||
if any("xmuijdswly" in w for w in data):
    print("FOUND IT")
```

is much faster than:

```
# 0m13.476s
for d in data:
    if "xmuijdswly" == d:
        print("FOUND IT")
        break
```

my data contains `10^7` arbitrary strings of average length `30`

**EDIT**: the time difference exists in both linux *and* windows:

```
PS ... > Measure-Command { python test_any.py }
TotalSeconds      : 4.5402383

PS ...> Measure-Command { python test_for.py }
TotalSeconds      : 17.7107506
```

**EDIT**: generating random strings program (for completeness)

```
$ cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fl=fopen("input.txt", "w+t");
    for (int i=0;i<10000000;i++)
    {
        int length = 5 + rand() % 50;
        for (int j=0;j<length;j++)
            fprintf(fl, "%c", rand() % 26 + 'a');
        fprintf(fl, "\n");
    }
    fclose(fl);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your two benchmarks are performing different tests. The first one, with the for loop, is matching a string against a list of strings by testing for equality. The second one, is using the `in` operator testing whether one string is a substring of another and would be a more expensive operation than testing for equality. But even if we change the second benchmark to instead test for equality, which should make it run even faster, I find the results to be the opposite of what you found, i.e. using `any` runs more slowly than the for loop. In the following demo I have arranged it that both benchmarks must iterate through all 10_000_000 strings because a match will never be found:

```py
import time

data = ['-' * 30 for _ in range(10_000_000)]

def test1():
    for d in data:
        if 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123' == d:
            return True
    return False

def test2():
    return any('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123' == w for w in data)

t = time.time()
b = test1()
print(b, time.time() - t)

t = time.time()
b = test2()
print(b, time.time() - t)
```

Prints:

```
False 0.2701404094696045
False 0.5590765476226807
```

The second version using `any` runs twice as slowly (perhaps you should re-check your results). **Why does the version using `any` actually run more slowly?**

The argument to `any` is a generator expression, which results in creating a generator function. So to test each value of the data a function call to generate the next comparison result must be made and that function call is what is making things run more slowly. We can turn your `any` version into one that uses an explicit generator function:

```py
import time

data = ['-' * 30 for _ in range(10_000_000)]

def test1():
    for d in data:
        if 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123' == d:
            return True
    return False

def generator():
    for w in data:
        yield 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123' == w

def test2():
    return any(generator())

t = time.time()
b = test1()
print(b, time.time() - t)

t = time.time()
b = test2()
print(b, time.time() - t)
```

Prints:

```None
False 0.28400230407714844
False 0.5430142879486084
```

As you can see, the time required for both `any` versions is essentially the same, as I would expect.

**Update: Using the OP's C Program to Generate the Data**

Here I used the OP's C program to generate the data and I have used the same "xmuijdswly" string for the comparison:

```py
import time

total_length = 0
data = []
with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        total_length += len(line)
        data.append(line)
print('Average string length:', total_length / len(data))

def test1():
    for d in data:
        if 'xmuijdswly' == d:
            return True
    return False

def test2():
    return any('xmuijdswly' == w for w in data)

t = time.time()
b = test1()
print(b,  'Time using for loop:', time.time() - t)

t = time.time()
b = test2()
print(b, 'Time using any:', time.time() - t)
```

Prints:

```None
Average string length: 29.4972984
False Time using for loop: 0.3110032081604004
False Time using any: 0.6610157489776611
```

**One *Possible* Explanation for OP's Results**

The OP hasn't actually posted the *complete* programs that they were testing against, which presumably have to first read in the data from *input.txt*. If the `any` version was run second, the data in *input.txt* would have been cached by the operating system as a result of the looping version having read the file and therefore the I/O time to read the input data would be much less for the `any` version.

Was the time to do that initial creation of the `data` list erroneously included in the benchmark timings?

Comment: Oh I completely missed that typo, thanks, I fixed it and measured times again. As expected, the time differences got bigger, but they are still in favor of `any` ... very strange indeed. I double checked on both linux and windows and the results are the same.

Comment: I have updated the answer again with a possible explanation for our different results.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and effort ! you were right about the preliminary reading phase - it was *not* identical in the `for` and `any` ... when I used the same mechanism I get similar results to yours.

Answer (score 0):

`any` with generator expressions performs a lazy evaluation - as soon as you find first match it stops iterating. Meanwhile your if loop has to go through all the elements so it takes more time. If you add a break after the print they should take roughly similiar amounts of time.

Comment: I actually chose a word that is *not* in the data so this is not the reason :( ... I'll edit my question to make things clearer

Comment: The OP edited the question and added a break. But with the break the version that uses the for loop actually runs twice as fast as the version that uses `any` because the `any` version converts the generator expression into a generator function and therefore a function call must be made to get the next comparison value to test. You should have tried running this yourself.