# Python Json navigation, is for loop is the only option?

Tags: json, python-3.x

All the doc I find online relies on a `for` loop to navigate in a json in Python. Is there no other *faster* choice to perform the following action? Something like `myjson["values"][:]["id"]`?
Thanks.

MWE:

```py
import json
myjson = json.loads(str('{"total" : 3, "values" : [{"id": 10100,"name": "extra name"},{"id": 10101,"name": "awesome name"},{"id": 10102,"name": "strange name"}]}'))

# I want to print the json's id's, only method?
for i in myjson["values"]:
    print(i["id"])
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong with `[x['id'] for x in myjson['values']]`? What actual evidence do you have that something "faster" is needed? I suppose you could do something like `list(map(lambda x: x['id'], myjson['values']))` or `from operator import itemgetter; list(map(itemgetter('id'), myjson['values']))`. But really, why bother? A list-comp or for-loop is much more readable.

Comment: I am mostly wondering if there is something similar to the jq syntax, basically being able to navigate seamlessly in a json tree. And extract all keys of an array in a single line. `[x['id'] for x in myjson['values']]` do serves that purpose somehow. As for it being slower, infact for my curent purpose I do not need something faster. But I have read that for loops are generally things to be avoided if another solution exists, since they are iterrating through all members of the list. I wanted to know if that something exists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are list-comprehensions and functional functions faster than "for loops"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108488/are-list-comprehensions-and-functional-functions-faster-than-for-loops)

Comment: There's nothing special about json trees. They're composed of normal python dicts, lists, etc. So what you're asking is whether for-loops are the most efficient way to extract elements from dicts, lists, etc. There's no general answer to that: it depends on the context. See the linked question above for more details. There's no json-specific solution that will be any faster, since it must use the same underlying functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You almost made it. This is how you do it. You need to assign the return of `json.loads` to your `myjson` variable. You cannot use linebreaks between `json` and `loads`, it must be `json.loads` because `loads` is a function in the `json` module.

```py
import json

my_json = '{"total" : 3, "values" : [{"id": 10100,"name": "extra name"},{"id": 10101,"name": "awesome name"},{"id": 10102,"name": "strange name"}]}'
data = json.loads(my_json)

for i in data["values"]:
    print(i["id"])
```

Comment: Hi, yeah sorry I copy pasted wrongly. But sorry, my question is not "how to make the for loop" work but "is the for loop the only way of navigating through a json?". Thanks for your reply still

Comment: Well it depends on the JSON object, the `values` key in your JSON is an list/array, so you probably want to iterate over it with a for loop. Perhaps you could also use the `map` function for a more functional programming approach.