# Pandas Dataframe - Replacing None-like Values with None in All Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I need to clean up a dataframe whose columns come from different sources and have different types. This means that I can have, for example, string columns that contain "nan", "none", "NULL", (as a string instead of a None value).

My goal is to find all empty values and replace them with None. This works fine:

```
for column in df.columns:
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        if (str(row[column]).lower() == "none") or if (str(row[column]).lower() == "nan") or (str(row[column]).lower() == "null"):
            df.at[row.name, column] = None
```

But it is obviously not the best or fastest way to do it. How can I take advantage of Pandas operations or list comprehensions to do this substitution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a somewhat controversial topic (see e.g. [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108488/are-list-comprehensions-and-functional-functions-faster-than-for-loops/43677631#43677631)) but it's often said that list comprehensions are more computationally efficient than for loops, especially when iterating over pandas dataframes.

I also prefer using list comprehensions stylistically as it leads to fewer levels of indentation from nested loops/if statements.

Here's what it looks like for your use case:

```
for column in df.columns:
    vals_list = df[column].to_list()
    replaced = [None if str(x).lower() in ['nan', 'none', 'null'] else x for x in vals_list]
    df[column] = replaced
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain where my_series comes from?

Comment: Apologies, that should read ‘df[column]’. I have edited the answer and also added ‘str’ around x in the list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Simple approach, use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,'nan'],
                   ['none',3,'NULL']])

df_clean = df.mask(df.isin(["nan", "none", "NULL"]))
```

Or, if you want to update in place:

```
df[df.isin(["nan", "none", "NULL"])] = float('nan')
```

Output:

```
     0  1    2
0    1  2  NaN
1  NaN  3  NaN
```

Comment: seems like converting to a `str` and checking if the first character is an `n` would be more *efficient*, or just check `isinstance(blah, int)`, not sure about the `isinstance` overhead.

Comment: @JonnyHenly no, it would very likely be much less efficient. `isin` is quite fast. Also, this would potentially yield many false positives.

Comment: Is it implemented in C? It's hard to fathom that iterating over a length 3 array would be more efficient than comparing 2 characters.

Comment: Well, that's my bet (also `isin` is not iterating, it's based on hashes making search very fast). If you provide me with a counter-example I'll believe you. For now, you're the one making the speculation ;)

Comment: :) true, I don't really have a leg to stand on.

Comment: @Jonny `df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([1,'none'], size=1_000_000).reshape(1000,1000))` then compare `df.isin(["nan", "none", "NULL"])` and `df.apply(lambda s: s.astype(str).str.startswith('n'))` with `timeit`. Checking the string is >10 times slower (and it has many flaws) ;)

Comment: And that's even without lowercasing the string. Game, set and match. I concede

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! Please notice that converting to a string and checking if the first character is "n" is not an option, as I have many valid string fields that start with an n. The idea is to convert to string, and, if the lowercase content is either "none", "nan", or "null", replace it with None in the most efficient way.

Comment: @Irina if you have specific strings, I believe my proposed method is both the most straightforward and most efficient. No need to convert to string. Case is important however, let me know if this is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

A quick, and easy optimization:

```
for column in df.columns:
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        col = str(row[column]).lower()
        if (col == "none") or if (col == "nan") or (col == "null"):
            df.at[row.name, column] = None
```

No need to convert `row[column]` to a `str` and then iterate over each character 3 times.

Shorter code:

```
its_none = ['none', 'nan', 'null']
for column in df.columns:
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        if str(row[column]).lower() in its_none:
            df.at[row.name, column] = None
```

Even shorter (I imagine you're expecting a number) and more optimized:

```
for column in df.columns:
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        if str(row[column]).lower().startswith('n'):
            df.at[row.name, column] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use numpy you could do this as well (if the values in the fields are truly a string)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name' : ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two'],
    'A' : ['null', 'none', 'empty', 'Keep']
})

df['A'] = np.where(df['A'].isin(['null', 'none', 'empty']), '', df['A'])
df
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The columns could or could not be a string; that is where the need to convert to str comes from before checking.