# Efficient concatenation of byte data in python without creating a huge list?

Tags: python, string, scalability

Doing some computation that results in strings that contain byte data (the strings serve as byte arrays). Now this data needs to be sent to another program that expects all this data to be concatenated. From what you can read here, the best way to concatenate appears to be dumping the data into a list and then doing `''.join(lst)` but it appears to me that creating might incur a memory overhead .

Is there any way to enjoy the benefits of `''.join(lst)` without creating a long list?

It is not hard to approximate how big the complete string is going to be. Is there a way to allocate that space and just pour the data inside? For instance with something like numpy? Then convert it into a huge string?

Comment: `lst` can be a generator expression rather than an actual list.

Comment: @martineau, but python will construct a list anyway. If you pass a generator python will first construct a list as it has to do two passes over the data

Comment: @Padraic: Better to let python do it internally.

Comment: How is the data being sent to another program? Via a socket? If so, perhaps you could send the total size and then the pieces through the socket as they are generated.

Comment: What about using `io.StringIO`, "an in-memory stream for text I/O"? Use `write()` to append each string, then `getvalue()` to get the finished product. Disclaimer: I don't actually have  a clue whether this is a good idea. https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO

Comment: Actually, this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19926932/4618331 shows  that `str.join` is still the best way to go. The Python docs say so too.

Comment: @zehelvion, is memory your greatest concern?

Comment: @HappyLeapSecond The data is saved to a huge file which is uploaded later to the cloud

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It is a viable concern cause the strings aren't huge but there will be an unknown growing number of them. Could do this in C but I'd much rather do the computation in Python were code is imho flexible, maintainable and readable among other benefits.

Comment: @zehelvion: If the big string is going to be written to a file, couldn't you then just write the smaller strings to the file sequentially without joining them first?

Comment: @HappyLeapSecond That is a really great point but currently the functionality is invoked by existing architecture that expects one large string as the return value. That being said, perhaps the external code could expect many mini strings and just write them one by one into a single file. This is a very good idea.

Answer (score -1):

[`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) actually does not need a *list* to join, but any kind of *iterable*. Therefore you could work with [generators](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions), serving string after string:

```
def calculate_something():
    # do something
    data = b"Foobar"
    yield from data
    # do something else
    yield from other_function_returning_string_data()

final_results = ''.join(calculate_something())
```

The `yield from` syntax is [new since Python 3.3](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380), if you are using something below 3.3 `for c in data: yield c` should work as well.

Comment: Doing it like this (`yield from`) is effectively breaking each of the strings up into individual characters and then yielding each character of each one separately.